# Error in doing factor analysis

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I am doing factor analysis with 500 variables and 1316 records. I am getting the following error:

```
Error in solve.default(cv) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 2.5024e-18
```

The syntax I am using is:

```
factor.out1 <- factanal(covmat=cor(factor3, use="complete.obs"),factor=50,rotation="none")
```

Any suggestion will be of great help.

Thanks

Comment: For a first suggestion, provide a sample of your data

Answer (score 0):

```
   com.kakao.talk com.android.phone com.gau.go.launcherex com.android.browser com.android.contacts com.nhn.android.search com.kakao.story
1              61               616                     0                 363                   48                      0               4
2             180               192                     0                  70                   94                     60              10
3             270               109                     0                 411                   53                      0               0
4             610                55                     0                  23                   47                    201              18
5             653                 0                     0                  11                    0                    153              64
6             341               147                     0                   2                    0                     58             437
7             167               118                     0                   1                    1                    109               0
8               0               379                     0                   4                  289                    121               0
9            1254                93                  1434                 616                   86                      7             268
10           1907               111                   328                   0                  119                   1073               0
```

here is a sample of 10 obs and 7 rows

Comment: Thanks to all who have spent their time on this question. I standardized the data and then run factor analysis. It is working fine now.